# Не запускается эмулятор андроида в MAUI c#

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2022, maui

хочу запустить программу на эмуляторе андроида, но пишет ошибку при создании образа: [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Hyper-V включён, не могу понять в чем проблема :(

Comment: как я понимаю кнопка переустановить не помогла, да?

Comment: Битый образ, очевидно

Comment: Я переустановил и visual studio 2022, и сам образ андроида, и ничего.. Пишет что невозможно запустить эмулятор..